# Ensure that all string variables placed into HTML is either properly contextually encoded manually

Tags: owasp

Can anyone explain this OWASP recommendation - 
Ensure that all string variables placed into HTML or other web client code is either properly contextually encoded manually, or utilize templates that automatically encode contextually to ensure the application is not susceptible to reflected, stored and DOM Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) attacks.

Comment: This recommendation seems to be clear, this is the basic recommendation to avoid Cross Site Srcipting. what do you want to know ?

Comment: I wanted to know what does it mean by -" properly contextually encoded manually"

Comment: You should use an encoder like https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_Encoder_Project for Java